# Return events of a calendar room by graph gets "DelegatedCalendarAccessDenied" erro

Tags: sharepoint-online, apps-development, microsoft-graph, graph-api

i am facing a problem when trie to get a room using graph api. I already had two rooms created on my exchange environment and the request works just fina when i search their events with the request bellow

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/room3@email.com.br/events
```

but then i created a new room and when i try to get with the same request

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/room4@email.com.br/events
```

it gets the error:

```
{    "error": 

        {        "code": "DelegatedCalendarAccessDenied",        

                 "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.",        

                 "innerError": {            

                                         "request-id": "cb059196-02df-4186-bf35-a5fd1d184b30",            

                                         "date": "2019-08-22T20:14:48"       

                 }    

        }

}
```

What king of permission am i missing? Because it working with other rooms. Just new ones gets this erro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out how to make it work. I just have to access the calendar of the room i created by following the steps:

[image]

[image]

[image]

After that, i just have to wait few hours for this to work.